# How do I make bad pointer arithmetic more obvious in C?

Tags: c, pointers, refactoring

I found a bug in which a function expected to be passed a pointer to a single struct, but new code then indexed the pointer, resulting in writing off the edge of the array.

```
void DoTheThing(struct Foo *foo, int index) {
    foo[index].value = bar(index);
}
```

The caller indexed the array and passed a pointer to a particular element, as intended:

```
struct Foo all_the_foos[2];

void DoAllTheThings() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        DoTheThing(&all_the_foos[i], i);
    }
}
```

Of course, this is a bug, since the called function ends up accessing `all_the_foos[i+i]`. Is there any way to refactor this code so that the error is more obvious, so this doesn't happen again?

Comment: and the error is...

Comment: This code could be valid... if there was a magic solution to find bug, people will use it ;)

Comment: @FredLarson it is hidden in the `&all_the_foos[i]` ... I guess...

Comment: protect `foo[foo->index]` by checking `foo->index` inside 0 .. 3

Comment: If you mean clarifying that DoTheThing takes a pointer to a single Foo rather than to an array of Foos, the only thing you can do is comments.

Comment: The clarification could be another function parameter - the number of elements.

Comment: Why `i < 3` when the array has 4 elements? Oh dang, you just changed the question.

Comment: @Weather How would that help. When passing the number as one, how do you know if foo is an array of length one or a pointer to a single foo?

Comment: @FredK an array of length `1` is the same as a pointer to a single value. A pointer may be indexed to any number of elements as an array, providing that memory is allocated for them.

Comment: I hate it when the OP immediately corrects code faults. Rolled back.

Comment: @WeatherVane, actually, I had asked the OP to fix the question. Unless the Foo struct has an index field, the code won't even compile.

Comment: @jwdonahue I missed that, sorry. But fixing the question detail doesn't mean changing the question.

Comment: Please stop the rollback war:(

Comment: Editing a question in such a way as to invalidate existing answers is unfriendly:(

Comment: @MartinJames thank you. The OP ***found a bug like this*** so it is only needs correction in an answer.

Comment: Interestingly, you can specify in a function declaration that a function will receive a pointer to at least a certain number of elements, as with `void DoTheThing(struct Foo foo[static 3])`. But I do not actually know what the value of that is (except it means NULL cannot be passed, since something must be there), and it will not help in this case, except as decoration.

Comment: I still think the foo->index is not actually part of the code the OP found, and it's a confounding typo, but then we still don't have the struct to prove it.

Comment: Let the OP ask their own question. An edit by an OP is evidence the new text more accurately conveys their intent. If it still needs fixing, work with them. If it invalidates an answer, so be it. Answers can be edited too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you gave a good answer. But OP clearly states he "found a bug". He doesn't say whether it is his code or another's. So let the bug he found, remain, as the bug he found please, and not a moving target.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The bug is clear; `DoTheThing` was passed a pointer to particular element of the array but `DoTheThing` indexed it as if it were an array. Thus, the caller and the callee both added an index, and the duplicated addition caused the bounds of the array to be exceeded. The OP wants to know how to make this error apparent and/or avoid it. If you did not understand that from the question, then let the OP edit it to express their intent better or, now that it has been explained to you, edit the question to express it better. Rolling back the OP’s edit does not help.

Comment: So why wasn't that in your answer?

Comment: @WeatherVane: If you are asking why the explanation of the bug was not in my answer, the answer to that is that the OP’s question does not ask us to find the bug. The question is not “What is the bug here?” The question is “How do I make this bug more obvious?”

Comment: @EricPostpischil the question "refactor this code so that the error is more obvious" is a hiding to nowhere. The answer is to fix the error, as you already answered.

Comment: I've decided to change the function signature to DoTheThing(struct Foo foo[1]), which is semantically identical but somewhat clearer (and might aid static analyzers in finding the bug). [answer in the form of a comment because this question should stay closed].

Comment: @Nicholas: If you made an edit, I do not see it in the edit history. I was making an edit at the same time, but Stack Overflow did not inform me of any conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can’t think of any C semantics that would cause the compiler to issue warnings or errors to help you out. That leaves alternatives that are a matter of human discipline. Some notions are:

- Always document functions, and document code generally. State clearly what the inputs are, what requirements there are, and what the results are. This will not only avoid many errors in the first place, it will help you crystallize the design in your mind, make it better, and write code that conforms to the design. (Having to write a sentence explaining why something works or what the limit on some loop or array is induces you to think about it more precisely. It is a **great** exercise.)
- Test. Ensure functions are tested at their boundaries and anywhere else “interesting.” (Boundaries include anywhere behavior is about to change. Most commonly, that includes the lowest allowed value of an index [because lower is illegal, so that is a change] and the highest allowed value, but there may be others.) Either craft test cases that exercise these and will report a bug if the code is wrong for them or write unit tests (special code that calls particular functions for testing, without running your whole program).
- Adopt a policy of declaring a parameter with `[]` when it is an array and `*` when it is a pointer to a single element. Additionally, why pass the index if the pointer points directly to the desired element? *E.g.*, `void DoTheThing(struct Foo *foo)` versus `void DoTheThing(struct Foo foo[], int index)`.
- Adopt a policy of always passing the number of elements in the thing that is passed. Somebody passing an array passes the total number of elements. Somebody passing one element passes 1. Then the called function can bounds-check any index it uses. (Which may affect performance, but can be worthwhile.)

Comment: Good suggestions.  Also, unit-tests that cover boundary conditions can help catch some corner cases early in development and provide tested use cases for developers to follow in development code.

Comment: @jwdonahue: Thanks, updated.

Comment: How would you write a test to catch this bug?

Comment: @Nicholas: It is hard to test for invalid memory being accessed, since the memory access may be permitted by the hardware. But you can write a test case that works only if the expected values are in the accessed memory. E.g., initialize `all_the_foos`, and write some test case that uses `all_the_foos[N-1]`, where `N` is the number of them. The test case should report an error if it gets the wrong results. Then, if `all_the_foos[(N-1)+(N-1)]` is used instead of `all_the_foos[N-1]`, it will likely have bad data in it, so the wrong results will be returned, and the test will report a bug.